# Throws Exception while instantiating class

Tags: java, list, class, constructor, instantiation

I have a very simple problem-

I have a class named `DEClient` whose constructor is like this-

```
public DEClient(List<DEKey> keys) {
    process(keys);
}
```

And `DEKey`  class is like this-

```
public class DEKey {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    public DEKey(){
        name = null;
        value = null;
    }

    public DEKey(String name, String value){
        this.name  = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to instantiate `DEClient` constructor. So for that I need to have `List<DEKey>`.

So what I did is I instantiated `DEKey` class like below using `service.getKeys()` (which will return `String`) and `id` as the value.

```
DEKey dk = new DEKey(service.getKeys(), id);

//The below line throws exception whenever I am running.
DEClient deClient = new DEClient((List<DEKey>) dk);
```

What wrong I am doing here?

Comment: What is `bk` (not `dk`) and what's with the explicit cast, (which wouldn't be needed if `bk` is a `List<DEKey>`)?

Comment: @A--C, Oops, while editing the code, I forgot to edit one word. I just updated the code with dk. By mistake it was `dk`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you even read your code before submitting ???? `dk` is a `DEKey`, why are you casting it into a `list<DeKey>`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first make a `List`, then add your key to that `List`. Casting like you have done is not the way to do it, since `DEKey` is *not* a `List` and casting into it will throw a `ClassCastException`.

```
DEKey dk = new DEKey(service.getKeys(), id);

List<DEKey> list = new ArrayList<DEKey>();
list.add (dk);

DEClient deClient = new DEClient(list);
```